# openssl1.1.1 and php7.2 send weird set of supported protocols on handshake

Tags: php, openssl

This morning an `openssl1.1.1` marked as a security update was delivered on my machine through the official ubuntu repositories.

It didn't take long to find that the php's openssl exntension behaviour changed.

```php
<?php

$address = 'tcp://216.58.199.46:443';
$timeout = 30;

$flags = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT;

$socket = stream_socket_client($address, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, $flags);
stream_set_timeout($socket, $timeout);

stream_set_blocking($socket, true);

stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT);
```

(the IP address is for `google.com`)

Now if I run wireshark that's what I see inside the packet:

```
Extension: supported_versions (len=5)
    Type: supported_versions (43)
    Length: 5
    Supported Versions length: 4
    Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
    Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

So, the client for some reason sends 1.3 as a supported protocol, and server happily chooses it.

If I only specify `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT` - then `tls1.2` is negotiated as expected.

Hence a question, is it me missing something in the TLS protocol, or there is a bug in php's openssl extension (or in openssl itself)?

Comment: Do you mean that when specifying `tls1.2` and `tls1.1` in the php client code, you get that client to send `tls1.3` and `tls1.2` on the network?

Comment: @oliv that's correct: the fragment captured using wireshark is generated by the code above.

Comment: It seems that [tls1.3 was enabled by default recently in php](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3c056a9e75c75def254b841ebe217256a01b5fc8). So maybe that selecting more than one method results in having tls1.3. This doesn't explain why tls1.1 is not selected though.

Comment: @oliv I also observe it on php 7.2.19